# How to access active warning filters list?

Tags: python, warnings

In python, after I set some filter with `warnings.filterwarning` (or some package I import does), how can I access the list of active filters? I tried `sys.warnoptions` but it always gives me an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I found it looking at the source code. It's `warnings.filters`.